# What type of plant is this???:)

Tags: identification, houseplants

I'm a bit clueless when it comes to plants and gardening but I got this houseplant as a gift a while ago and I was wondering if someone could identify what type of plant it is for me.( I was thinking it might be a peace lily but it has no flowers)[image: ous] [image]Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like peace lilly.

Spathiphyllum wallisii, commonly known as peace lily, white sails, or spathe flower is a very popular indoor house plant of the family Araceae. The genus name means "spathe-leaf", and the specific epithet is named after Gustav Wallis, the German plant collector.